# Leetcode Same Tree

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve same tree from leetcode with python. 
original problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/

My code was able to pass a few test cases but not all. It couldn't pass the submission. My idea is to flatten the tree and compare the two lists. The failed case is at the bottom of the code.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        """
        :type p: TreeNode
        :type q: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        def flatten(root):
            if root is None:
                return ["null"]
            if root.left is None and root.right is None:
                return [root.val]
            if root.left is None:
                # print 'left', [root.val, "null", flatten(root.right)]
                return [root.val, "null", flatten(root.right)]
            if root.right is None:
                # print 'right', [root.val, flatten(root.left), "null"]
                return [root.val, flatten(root.left), "null"]
            else: 
                # print flatten(root.right) + flatten(root.right)
                return flatten(root.right) + flatten(root.right)

        return flatten(p) == flatten(q)



## Failed test case
## [390,255,2266,-273,337,1105,3440,-425,4113,null,null,600,1355,3241,4731,-488,-367,16,null,565,780,1311,1755,3075,3392,4725,4817,null,null,null,null,-187,152,395,null,728,977,1270,null,1611,1786,2991,3175,3286,null,164,null,null,4864,-252,-95,82,null,391,469,638,769,862,1045,1138,null,1460,1663,null,1838,2891,null,null,null,null,3296,3670,4381,null,4905,null,null,null,-58,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,734,null,843,958,null,null,null,1163,1445,1533,null,null,null,2111,2792,null,null,null,3493,3933,4302,4488,null,null,null,null,null,null,819,null,null,null,null,1216,null,null,1522,null,1889,2238,2558,2832,null,3519,3848,4090,4165,null,4404,4630,null,null,null,null,null,null,1885,2018,2199,null,2364,2678,null,null,null,3618,3751,null,4006,null,null,4246,null,null,4554,null,null,null,1936,null,null,null,null,2444,2642,2732,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4253,null,null,null,null,2393,2461,null,null,null,null,4250,null,null,null,null,2537]

## [390,255,2266,-273,337,1105,3440,-425,4113,null,null,600,1355,3241,4731,-488,-367,16,null,565,780,1311,1755,3075,3392,4725,4817,null,null,null,null,-187,152,395,null,728,977,1270,null,1611,1786,2991,3175,3286,null,164,null,null,4864,-252,-95,82,null,391,469,638,769,862,1045,1138,null,1460,1663,null,1838,2891,null,null,null,null,3296,3670,4381,null,4905,null,null,null,-58,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,734,null,843,958,null,null,null,1163,1445,1533,null,null,null,2111,2792,null,null,null,3493,3933,4302,4488,null,null,null,null,null,null,819,null,null,null,null,1216,null,null,1522,null,1889,2238,2558,2832,null,3519,3848,4090,4165,null,4404,4630,null,null,null,null,null,null,1885,2018,2199,null,2364,2678,null,null,null,3618,3751,null,4006,null,null,4246,null,null,4554,null,null,null,1936,null,null,null,null,2444,2642,2732,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4253,null,null,null,null,2461,2393,null,null,null,null,4250,null,null,null,null,2537]
```

Comment: Please include everything necessary to understand the issue in the question itself.

Comment: I quess you should replace `[root.val, "null", flatten(root.right)]` with `[root.val, "null"] + flatten(root.right)` since `flatten(root.right)` is a list. The same modification is needed for `[root.val, flatten(root.left), "null"]`. Probably you also should use `None` instead of `"null"`.

Comment: @poolka, neither solves the problem.. :( it still failed for the same test case

Comment: @glibdud, what's not clear?

Comment: @SoPia It's discouraged to make people visit an external link to find the description of the problem your code is trying to solve.

Comment: @glidud i could paste the problem here but it's not very readable :(

Comment: Given two binary trees, write a function to check if they are the same or not.Two binary trees are considered the same if they are structurally identical and the nodes have the same value.
Example 1:

Input:     1         1
          / \       / \
         2   3     2   3

        [1,2,3],   [1,2,3]

Output: true
Example 2:

Input:     1         1
          /           \
         2             2

        [1,2],     [1,null,2]

Output: false
Example 3:

Input:     1         1
          / \       / \
         2   1     1   2

        [1,2,1],   [1,1,2]

Output: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if two trees are identical, you need to determine that the structure is the same i.e equal nodes at the same level and branch. You can write a recursive function that loops over the tree and creates a [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) encoding, which can later be used to compare the nodes:

```
class Solution(object):
   @classmethod
   def tree_paths(cls, _tree:TreeNode, _paths = []):
     yield [_tree.val, _paths]
     if _tree.left is not None:
       yield from cls.tree_paths(_tree.left, _paths+[0])
     if _tree.right is not None:
       yield from cls.tree_paths(_tree.right, _paths+[1])
   def isSameTree(self, p, q):
     if p is None and q is None:
        return True
     if not all([p, q]):
        return False
     _tree1, _tree2 = list(self.__class__.tree_paths(p)), list(self.__class__.tree_paths(q))
     if len(_tree1) != len(_tree2):
       return False
     return all(a == b and all(c ==d for c, d in zip(j, l)) for [a, j], [b, l] in zip(_tree1, _tree2))
```

---

To test, a tree with the same attributes as the original `TreeNode` can be created:

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs:dict) -> None:
     self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['val', 'left', 'right']}

t1 = TreeNode(val=1, left=TreeNode(val=2), right=TreeNode(val=3))
t2 = TreeNode(val=1, left=TreeNode(val=2), right=TreeNode(val=3))
t3 = TreeNode(val=1, left=TreeNode(val=2), right=TreeNode(val=4))
print(Solution().isSameTree(t1, t2))
print(Solution().isSameTree(t1, t3))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

This answer was successfully accepted on LeetCode.

[image]

Edit: Your code is close, however, `flatten(root.right) + flatten(root.right)` must be changed, as you are finding the path of nodes on the right subtree twice. Also, you have to include the value of the current tree instance passed to `isSameTree`. Thus, `flatten(root.right) + flatten(root.right)` must become:

```
return flatten(root.left)+[root.val]+flatten(root.right)
```

Comment: could you explain what's wrong with my code? i understand there are multiple ways to solve it